# Make a NullObject evaluate to falsy in Ruby

Tags: ruby, design-patterns

After implementing [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern#Ruby) in a Rails application (also described in RubyTapas episode 112) I refactored out some code, but there's a syntax construct that seems to not work anymore.

I used to write statements like `current_user || redirect_out`, where, if current_user was set it would return it, and if it was `nil` it redirects out, but now `current_user` may be an instance of `Null::User` and thus "truthy", and that snippet would never redirect out.

I tried defining the `||` operator, but didn't work. Is there any way this syntax can still be used with null (but "truthy") objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have only halfway adopted that pattern, and have not correctly adopted its spirit. My understanding is that the very purpose of the pattern is to avoid `||`.

You should have some purpose for calling `current_user || redirect_out`, and that could be doing something with it, or getting some attribute of it. For example, suppose your code has:

```
(current_user || redirect_out).foo
```

When `current_user` is not an instance of `Null::User`, you wanted to call `foo` on it. In that case, what you should do is define `Null::User#foo` to be `redirect_out` (possibly followed by some more operations like `foo` on other classes).

```
class Null::User
  def foo; redirect_out ... end
end
```

and in place of `(current_user || redirect_out).foo`, you should just do

```
current_user.foo
```

When `current_user` is not a `Null::User` instance, it will call `foo`. When it is such instance, then the `redirect_out ...` routine will be called on it.

Answer (score 6):

I once wrote [an article](http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/05/30/null-objects-and-falsiness/) about how it's not possible to define "falsy" objects in Ruby, and why attempts to make a Null Object falsy are generally misguided.

Basically, the best you can do is come up with a confusingly inconsistent object using `#!`, `nil?`, etc.

As others have noted, usually when you want to make a Null Object "falsy" it's because you're not full leveraging polymorphism. The whole point of a Null Object is to avoid type checks, and checking for `NilClass` in the form of an `if` statement is just as much a type check as any other.

That said, sometimes it's unavoidable. That's why in my [Naught](http://github.com/avdi/naught) library I generate a helper conversion function called `Actual()` (among several other conversions). `Actual()` converts Null Objects back to `nil` values, but leaves all other objects alone. So for the cases where you need to switch on an object's truthiness, you can do it like this:

```
if Actual(obj_that_might_be_null)
  # ...do stuff...
end
```

Answer (score 4):

There are exactly two objects which are falsy in Ruby: `nil` and `false`. Period.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to define your own falsy objects, nor is it possible to override the Boolean operators (except for `not`/`!`). This is a shame, really: it is one of the basic pillars of OO that an object can simulate another object, but in Ruby it is not possible to simulate `false` or `nil`, therefore breaking one of the fundamental properties of OO in a language with an otherwise pretty good OO model.

Comment: I didn't know that you can override `not` and `!`.

Comment: @sawa: You can define a method named `!` which will called both by `!` and `not`.